# Azure Synapse pipeline notebook takes so long time

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I have worked on Microsoft azure synapse pipeline.

I used to worked it by myself before, but few days ago an coworker joined me and he worked the pipeline his own way.

The problem is, after he joined almost (Not every time) of time I run the pipeline, it takes a lot of time at 'Notebook' step (it usually took less than 5 min but it took more than 1 ~ 2 hours).

We thought the reason is because we had only one spark pool so we created more spark pools and let him use his own pool and I use my own pool so we don't share one.

However the problem didn't solved, it still took unreasonable time for processing notebook session.

Check the code in notebook but there were no script that takes huge time complexity, when it works well it really took less than 5 min.

Is spark pool really causing this problem? Is there anything I should do more than just creating another pool?

It is so weird because it didn't happen when I was using it alone but comes up after someone joined it.

Please help me, Thank you!